# qmake set install directory

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake, qwt

I'm trying to build [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) to a custom location. The obvious thing to try is a `PREFIX` option, but it had no effect and the `make install` still failed:

```
$ qmake qwt.pro PREFIX='/my/path'
$ make
$ make install
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/qwt-5.2.3': Permission denied
```

There seem to be numerous other questions and answers to this question, which also have no effect and fail:

- [How to change qmake PREFIX location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639459/how-to-change-qmake-prefix-location): `qmake -set prefix '/my/path'`
- [How can the install path be set for a qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217093/how-can-the-install-path-be-set-for-a-qt-project): `make; INSTALL_ROOT=/my/path; make install`

Any other suggestions?

---

*QMake version 2.01a

Using Qt version 4.5.3 in /opt/Qt4/4.5.2/qtsdk-2009.04/qt/lib

RHEL 5.10*

Comment: Have you seen this question: [Qt project files and PREFIX variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7106442/26449) ?

Comment: @Bill Yep. Seems like more of a solution for someone *writing* a qmake script, but I guess it could do. Where do I put that bit of code? In the `qwt.pro` file? (BTW, I don't have any *need* to use `PREFIX`. Isn't there some other environmental variable or command flag that doesn't require editing the provided script?)

Comment: I found this page: [Installing Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html#INSTALL). Looks like the default path (/usr/local/qwt-5.2.3) can be changed in a file called `qwtconfig.pri`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit the `qwtconfig.pri` file in the source directory, it has the installation path hardcoded for different platforms, as well as many other options you might want to change.